# How do I prevent the checkbox state from getting reset when the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, darkmode

I created a **button** which **activates dark mode** on my website but I want to change it from a **button to a checkbox** like the one from the following **CodePen** example:

```
https://codepen.io/mburnette/pen/LxNxNg
```

The **dark mode** was **stored in LocalStorage** and it works as expected when using a button and the theme **retains its state** even if the **page refreshed** but I am unsure how to do this with the **checkbox**.

I created **2 functions**, one for **activating dark mode and the other for disabling dark mode**. I linked the checkbox id at the top of the snippet.

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpSa1.png`

**If dark mode was selected** by the user and the **page is refreshed** then the **dark mode** should be retained**.

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O9Sz.png`

If the element is clicked the **dark mode setting are applied**

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Rpo.png`

The **checkbox triggers enabling and disabling dark mode** as expected in the following example

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwGkN.png`

However, when the page is refreshed the **checkbox state is reset** but it keeps the dark mode because of **LocalStorage**. This can be seen in the following example:

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV6fi.png`

I am unsure how to add the checkbox to LocalStorage so when the **checkbox is checked dark mode is triggered and when the page is refreshed they both keep their state**. Any information of how I could achieve this would be appreciated :)

Comment: please add all code here in the question rather than non hyperlinked links to external resources

Comment: @ Bob Jones  why don't you save a flag for this checkbox in backend part of your code and ```GET``` on page reload with this you can make sure that by changing browser the user will get the same settings

Comment: @iliya unfortunately I dont know how to do this because i'm still fairly new to web development

Answer (score 0):

You can store checkbox value in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`
ex.

```
 localStorage.setItem('checkBoxValue', input.checked)
```

or

```
 sessionStorage.setItem('checkBoxValue', input.checked)
```

Comment: Could you further elaborate on that e.g. should I do something like ->  **let toggleSwitch = localStorage.setItem('checkBoxValue', input.checked)** outside of the methods.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by using **darkModeToggle.checked = true;** in one of my methods and **false** in another method. Now the checkbox state is saved however, on reload there is a slight second when the dark mode is not applied and the toggle switch is changed to match the theme. If anyone knows a  fix to this that would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a heads up from experience, localStorage likes to randomly delete itself. If possible, saving preferences server side is a better option.